# regex to match all uppercase letters before the first question mark

Tags: regex

I am attempting to create a regex that will match all uppercase letters before the first question mark in a URL string:

`/foO/baR/?_heLLo=1320957051041105000&_woRld=0`

I have tried both the following:

`(?<!(\?))([A-Z])`
`(?<!\?.*?)([A-Z])`

The former captures uppercase letters before and after the question mark. The latter captures no uppercase letters. Any insight would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What if the string contains more than one question mark?

Comment: Using Java, so I can port it over.  String will be a URL string, so I will clarify the question via edit: "before the first question mark."

Comment: What if the string does not contain a question mark?

Comment: What do you mean by "port it over"? Port it to what?

Comment: @MarkByers With no question mark, I would still want a match.  So, if question mark existed, the regex would only find a match before the question mark. If no QM existed, I would want it to use the entire string to find a match. By port it, I meant port your original Ruby regex to a Java-friendly regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=^[^?]*)[A-Z]
```

Comment: @MattC: Yes, it doesn't work on that site because Rubular is based on Ruby. Ruby's regular expression engine is missing some features such as lookbehinds. But you said you were using Java. Java has lookbehinds.

Answer (score 2):

This regex would do the trick:

```
[A-Z](?=.*?\?)
```

See it in action here: http://regexr.com?2v5r0