# create filter to ensure lowercase urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following code in the global.asax of my mvc web application:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Handles the BeginRequest event of the Application control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ensure that all url's are of the lowercase nature for seo
        string url = Request.Url.ToString();
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET" && Regex.Match(url, "[A-Z]").Success)
        {
            Response.RedirectPermanent(url.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), true);
        }
    }
```

What this achieves is to ensure all url's accessing the site are in lower case. I would like to follow the MVC pattern and move this to a filter that can applied globally to all filters.

Is this the correct approach? And how would I create a filter for the above code?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with leaving your code in the `BeginRequest` method. However, to answer your question: move the code to a filter, as you already know, and then create, if you don't have one already, a (preferably abstract) BasePageController that is decorated with your new filter. That way your filter will execute on all Action methods in controller classes that inherit from your base. Another option would be to create an HttpHandler with the same code. The advantage of this is that handlers execute earlier in the request lifecycle and should yield better performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I ensure lower case URLs on POST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349588/how-do-i-ensure-lower-case-urls-on-post)

Answer (score 1):

My opinion - a filter is too late to handle a global url rewrite.  But to answer your question as to how, create an action filter:

```
public class LowerCaseFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // ensure that all url's are of the lowercase nature for seo
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var url = request.Url.ToString();
        if (request.HttpMethod == "GET" && Regex.Match(url, "[A-Z]").Success)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), true);
        }
    }
}
```

and in FilterConfig.cs, register your global filter:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); 
        filters.Add(new LowerCaseFilterAttribute());
    }
}
```

**HOWEVER**, I would recommend pushing this task out to IIS and using a rewrite rule.  Make sure the [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) is added to IIS and then add the following rewrite rule in your web.config:

```
<!-- http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/ -->
<rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="GET" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```